# React-Native + Redux: fetching data from API as an array of objects and rendering in list component

Tags: arrays, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I've been learning React-Native + Redux and have recently hit a wall while trying to build a relatively small app.  My problem is that when I fetch json data from an api (from another one of my apps) using `axios`, the data comes in the form of an array of objects (e.g. all the door objects).  Whenever i try to transfer that array to my component through my reducer, the data gets lost and the array turns up empty every time

My action creator, which uses `redux-thunk`:

```
export const doorsFetch = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/doors')
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS, payload: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data));
  };
};
```

My DoorsReducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = [];

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  console.log(action.payload);
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The `action.payload` console.log turns up what i would expect, an array like this [{object}, {object}].  However in my component the array becomes empty, so i think the problem is in the reducers or in how I map the state to props.

I've also tried the doorReducer this way:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  doors: []
};
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, doors: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

with the same result of an empty array in the component props.

Here is my reducers index:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import OrientationReducer from './OrientationReducer';
import TraitsReducer from './TraitsReducer';
import DoorsReducer from './DoorsReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  orientation: OrientationReducer,
  traits: TraitsReducer,
  doorState: DoorsReducer
});
```

And finally my component, DoorList:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ListView } from 'react-native';
import { doorsFetch } from '../actions';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

class DoorList extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.doorsFetch();

    this.createDataSource(this.props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.createDataSource(nextProps);
  }

  createDataSource({ doors }) {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(doors);
  }

  renderRow(door) {
    return <ListItem door={door} />;
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);  // for testing

    return (
      <ListView
        enableEmptySections
        dataSource={this.dataSource}
        renderRow={this.renderRow}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    doors: state.doorState
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { doorsFetch })(DoorList);
```

When I console out `this.props`, I get an object with a doors array that is empty.  I can't seem to figure out what happened to the data and how to render it properly in the view.  Any insight would be much appreciated.  Would happily provide more code/info if requested.

EDIT:

For clarification, this is where i put my console.log statements for debugging purposes:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = [];

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  console.log(action.payload);
  console.log(action.type);
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS:
      console.log('fetching doors case triggered');
      return [...state, ...action.payload];
    default:
      console.log('not working!');
      return state;
  }
};
```

SOLUTION:

On top of the suggested corrections below, the other glaring issue was that my `FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS` constant was improperly imported from another file, and so was undefined in the reducer file.  Therefore my switch statement didn't pick it up and it went to the default case. I was missing curly brackets around `FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS`.

Comment: Keep in mind that the first render will have an empty bunch of doors because the fetch hasn't completed yet. I don't know about debugging React Native, but if you can check what's happening in your `mapStateToProps` you can see if you're getting what you expect. I'm assuming the current `DoorList` code is assuming the first approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `action.payload` is an array, you also need to put the spread operator on it to properly combine it with the array in `state`:

Change:

```
case FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS:
  return [...state, action.payload];
```

to:

```
case FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS:
  return [...state, ...action.payload];
```

It also looks like you're not returning the promise from axios.get():

Change this:

```
return (dispatch) => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/doors')
```

to

```
return (dispatch) => {
  return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/doors')
```

Comment: thanks for that correction.  On further inspection, I learned that my `FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS` action is not being triggered, but rather the default in the switch statement.  No wonder my array is empty.  So my action creator is the issue..

Comment: Updated my answer. Also looks like you need to add "return " before your "axios.get()"

Comment: hm still isn't working.  The default case is still triggered.  i know it's hitting the api and response.data is what i expect.  but i guess the reducer is not receiving the FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS action

Comment: When you say the "default case is still triggered"... when it does, what is your action.type at that time? Could FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS be undefined by any chance?

Comment: I console.logged `action.type` right before the switch statement and got 'fetch_doors_success' which is what i would expect.  strange.  FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS is a shared constant from another 'types.js' file that equals 'fetch_doors_success'.  However, my console.log in the default case is appearing and not the one for FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS

Comment: i show the placement of my console.log statements in an edit to original post for clarification

Comment: Sounds strange... I'd also add "console.log(FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS);"  and "console.log(action.type === FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS);" as a sanity check.  I mean, if the strings are really equal, you switch/case should work.

Comment: Wow so i did what you suggested and they were not equal.  FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS was undefined.  when i just manually put in the string 'fetch_doors_success' for the switch statement it worked!  Thank you so much for helping me pin this down!  After staring at my import statement for a while I finally noticed that my FETCH_DOORS_SUCCESS was missing curly brackets around it!

Comment: You're very welcome!  every once in a while, we all need another set of eyes 8-)